# Alternate to print greater than (>) symbol in Ubuntu

Tags: java, terminal, ubuntu-13.04

May be this question is too easy but it took a lot my time but I could not figure out. I am trying to execute `echo` command in which I am trying to append some data in a text file. Everything works when run in terminal but when I try to run it through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo my text >> file.txt")`, then >> does not work.

Is there any way to give code or something so that this command should work? I tried `&gt;` but it did not work for me.

Comment: Did you try with `echo 'my text' >> file.txt`?

Comment: Yes. It works fine. I tried like this too. `echo \'my text\' >> file.txt`. This works fine. Thats why I was asking about alternative of `>`.

Comment: Why aren't you adding the text line directly in your Java code?

Comment: its not working directly.

Comment: @TauqeerAhmad I meant, did you try adding the two single quotes in the java string? Then, ErstwhileIII is right, why don't you use the java IO api and directly write to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: In which shell should the echo command be executed? Runtime.exec can get a cmdArray. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[]%29

```
import java.io.*;

class RuntimeExecLinux {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      try {
        // Execute a command with arguments
        String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "echo 'my text from java' >> file.txt"};
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        cmd = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "cat file.txt"};
        child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        // Get the input stream and read from it
        InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)c);
        }
        in.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Greetings

Axel